# Which OS recommended for Programmers?

Tags: python, linux, qt

My stack for web developing includes Django/Python and Qt/C++ for non-web developing.
What is most comfortable OS for a developer with such a stack ?

Comment: "Doesn't make a damn bit of difference" or "whichever one you are most productive on". Take a pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: nobody cares...if you are fine with Windows, use Windows. If you are commandline guy, go with a Unix system...the distro unlikely matters...

Answer (score 1):

Once you go linux, you'll never go back (though you might go crazy and move onto bsd).  Ubuntu is probably the easiest OS to start with, if only because of the truckloads of documentation, forum assistance, etc.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an language that has special requirements (like .net), the question should be `which os does the programmer recommend`.

That's really a personal decision.